# Set indentation for shell script function

Tags: indentation, shell-mode, bash

I am trying to set the number of spaces per indent for starting a new function in `sh-mode` (bash sub-mode). I have tried setting:

```
'(sh-basic-offset 2)
'(sh-indentation 2)
'(smie-indent-basic 2)
```

(as shown in `custom-set-variables` in `.emacs`) and some others as well, but none of them have had any effect!

Comment: The way to set variables is not via `custom-set-variables` (which is the thing used internally by Customize but is not meant to be used by hand).  Better use things like `(setq sh-basic-offset 2)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting `sh-basic-offset` to the required indentation is what is needed - but what I didn't realise is, it's also necessary to close and reopen all shell script files before the customisation takes effect. I can't remember ever having to do this before in emacs.

Comment: After changing `.emacs`, you must either quit emacs and restart it, or use `M-x load-file` to reload your `.emacs` If you want to reload a file that you have open in your editor, you can say `C-x C-v RETURN` to "revisit" it.

Comment: @AlexL load-file does not work in this particular case. Like I said, this is very unusual. Usually simply customising a variable is sufficient.

Comment: Hmm...do you know why this would be @robin-green? I'm curious.

Comment: You can also use `M-x set-variable` if you want to just change this for the buffer you are working in.

Comment: Worth noting that nowadays the effect is immediate, i.e. no need to reopen the file.

Answer (score 4):

I set-basic-offset to 2 but that didn't seem to work, I went back pressed `C-h v sh-<TAB>` and realized that there was a `sh-indentation` I set that variable to 2 and everything seems to work like a charm now.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "set-basic-offset" and also clarify exactly *how* you "set that variable to 2".

Comment: The forum omitted tab because I placed in between the greater than and less than character.  C-h v sh- "press tab" autocomplete will show you a list of variables.

Comment: I fixed your markup, but your comment still doesn't explain what you meant by "set-basic-offset" nor *how* you "set that variable to 2".

Comment: This variable is obsolete since 26.1, use `sh-basic-offset` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same experience as Albaro: setting sh-basic-offset having no effect, but setting sh-indentation working as expected.

In my case, I evaluated `(setq sh-basic-offset 2)` from with emacs, eg. via M-x eval-expression. I am running `GNU Emacs 25.2.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.21) of 2017-09-22, modified by Debian`. My major mode is Shell-script.