# Using a sh-basic-offset value with a multiple of tab-width has side effects when building function using "C-c ("

Tags: shell-mode

When using a multiple of the `tab-width` value for `sh-basic-offset`, creating a function using the built-in command `C-c (` removes characters from the expected result.  That being said, I can create a shell function by manually typing it.  It is just this built-in command, which causes odd behavior.

When `tab-width` and/or `sh-basic-offset` are not set inside the `.emacs` file or the latter is not a multiple of the former, it works as expected.

Here are the tests I did:
In the below examples I use "asdf" as the function name and the pipe character ("|") is the visualization of where point is located after I completed the built-in command.

With either variables not defined or not a multiple of one another, the (default) result is:

```
function asdf() {
    |
}
```

With both set to 4, the result is:

```
function asdf() {}|
```

With `tab-width` set to 4 and `sh-basic-offset` to 8, the result is:

```
function asdf()}|
```

With both set to 8, the result is:

```
function asdf}|
```

With both set to 16 (just for a test), the result is (semantically a rather amusing):

```
fu}|
```

Is this a bug or do I need to set another variable to a certain value for it to work?  I at least tried the variables stated in [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/24719/23319), but they did not have any effect at all for this issue.

Comment: I can replicate that.  Please `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: @phils, thanks.  I reported it now to the GNU Emacs maintainers.

Comment: Great, thank you.

Comment: bug#36480: 26.2; Using a sh-basic-offset value with a multiple of tab-width has side effects when building function using “C-c (”